# remote: Repository not found in GitHub pipeline

Tags: github, pipeline, github-actions

I'm trying to checkout a private repo inside my GitHub pipeline, and the following is my pipeline code,

```
build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:  
  - name: Checkout pickezy backend
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
     repository: Madurad/jenkinsfiles
     token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
     ref: master
```

But when I run this I get the following error saying, "repository not found" but it's in my githiub org. and it's a private repo.

[image]

It does not seem like an auth error. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Anything I've missed?

Answer (score 6):

You can add the missing permission in the top level of the YAML file:

```
permissions:
  contents: read
```

Note that I did not need to specify `token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` in the checkout step.

*This solution is based on an auto-completion from GitHub Copilot. It works, but I did no further research.*

Answer (score 4):

You can observe on [the Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) that the `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have all available permissions.

*In this specific case, the permission to access the private repository.*

If you want to perform specific operations in your workflows involving other permissions, you'll need to create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with the wished permissions and use it instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` (adding it as a secret).

---

In your case, the workflow will look like this:

```yaml
build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:  
  - name: Checkout pickezy backend
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
     repository: Madurad/jenkinsfiles
     token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
     ref: master
```

Comment: I tried the way you told, but now getting different error "Error: Input required and not supplied: token"

Comment: Did you create the Personal Access Token and add it as a repository secret? This error occurs generally when the secret is empty.