Error 403 on github actions even after authentication
I have a github config which builds docker with Dockerfile that pulls from a private registry, am getting a 403 error when I have already authenticated, so am not sure if the authentication is for just pushing or error is raised because it pulls container from a different repository, here is the part config:
  - name: Login to docker
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      registry: ghcr.io
      username: ${{ github.actor }}
      password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  
  - name:  Build docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
    with:
      context: ./api
      push: true
      tags: ghcr.io/org/app:latest

and here is the docker file
FROM ghcr.io/org/app-node AS builder

Now my understanding is since the login is already done both images belong to the same organization, I should have no problem pulling tafuta-node but am getting the error below:
ERROR: failed to solve: ghcr.io/***/***-node: failed to resolve source metadata for ghcr.io/***/***-node:latest: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://ghcr.io/v***/***/***-node/manifests/latest: 403 Forbidden

Any assistance will be highly appreciated here as am sort unclear on how to approach this now

The answer that really helped solved my problem is https://stackoverflow.com/a/74902591/3187105
But now also make sure in your permissions you have
contents: read
packages: write

